# Particular additive matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, integer-programming

I have a matrix that I need to decompose into a sum of individual matrices. I want to find the minimum number of individual matrices I need in order to do this. The individual matrices must have a particular form which I will explain in a moment.

So, a very simple example would be the following. My initial $3 \times 3$ matrix is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.4 & 0.3 \\
0.5 & 0.0 & 0.3 \\
0.5 & 0.6 & 0.0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrices that sum to this matrix must have each cell being $0$ or a particular number (call it $X_n$). If the entry in a cell is not zero then the symmetric cell must be zero (i.e. if cell $[1,3]$ is say $0.1$ then cell $[3,1]$ be must $= 0$). The sum of the $X_n$ must be $= 1$. So I could decompose the matrix above as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Matrix }1 &=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.3 & 0.3 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\text{Matrix }2&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\text{Matrix }3 & =
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 \\
 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\text{Matrix }4 &=
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
$$
The actual matrices I will have will be bigger than this and might have entries like 0.51678.

I have searched around, but this doesn't seem to be a standard decompsition problem. So my inital thought was to set it up as an integer programming problem (turning 0.51678 into 51678 say) and increase the number of types I allow until I get a feasible solution.

My question is if I am wrong and there is a standard algorithm for doing this, or whether the integer approach seems stupid and another approach would be better.

I would be very grateful for any thoughts.

(If it matters, I mostly program in R but can use Python, Julia ... too).

Comment: Thank you for the edits, the matrices look much better. I didn't realise you could insert tex code.

Comment: Do you need to get a provably minimal number of terms, or are you okay with a "reasonable" but not necessarily minimal number?

Comment: I suppose I had been thinking that the approach might be partly algorithmic, so I would increase the number of types until a solution exists. At the moment I think there will always be a solution if none of the symmetric pairs in the original matrix sum to more than 1, and the number of types is bounded above by the number of off diagonal elements. This all sounds a bit nebulous and I would prefer to have some standard result I could use, but I couldn't find anything which is why I was posting I guess. So even if you had an idea for a reasonable number I would be very interested to hear it.

Comment: Matrix decomposition typically is used for expressing a matrix as the product of several other matrices, no? Would the sum necessarily even be unique?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Cholesky, QR etc are all factorisations into products. Maybe I have been sloppy with terminology. And, no, I don't think it will be unique, but I think there will be a minimum number of terms (if a solution exists).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether your $X_n$ scalars need be nonnegative, so I'll assume not (but will assume their absolute values are bounded by some constant $M$). Let $B$ be the matrix to which your terms must sum. Suppose you list out all possible matrices of the required form where the nonzero component is 1. So, for example, let $$A_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),$$ $$A_2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$ etc. The key here is that any matrix meeting your requirements to be a term in the sum will be a scalar multiple of one of these matrices. Now let $x_i \in [-M,M]$ and $y_i\in \{0,1\}$ be variables for $i=1,\dots,N$, where $N$ is the number of $A$ matrices you have. Your problem can be written as the mixed integer linear program $$\begin{align*}
\min & \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}\\
\textrm{s.t.} & \sum_{i=1}^{N}A_{i}x_{i}=B\\
 & -My_{i}\le x_{i}\le My_{i}\:\forall i.
\end{align*}$$Note that there is no need to round or rationalize the components of $B$. If the number of possible $A$ matrices is too large, you can use a subset of them and (assuming the subset provides  feasible model) get a suboptimal but possibly okay solution.

Comment: To add to @prubin's answer, if the number of possible $A$ matrices is too large but can be described implicitly by a set of constraints, you can start with a small number of them and use a technique called *column generation* to generate more as needed.

Comment: Thank you both so much. But actually, it was this generation of all the possible matrix types that I was hoping to avoid as I will have maybe a 20 by 20 matrix. So with each off diagonal pair being able to be chosen 3 ways this will give me a huge number. But then I will look at the column generation technique you mention. Thank you again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I want to be sure I understood well your problem. The fact that the symmetric of a non-zero cell must be equal to 0. Does it implies that you are making a sum of [triangular matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)?

I know that this kind of matrices is allowed in your examples (which is not a triangular matrice):

\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.3 & 0.3 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.3 & 0.0\\
\end{pmatrix}

But I think it can always be translated to a triangular matrix like that one:
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.3 & 0.3 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Yes, I didn't follow the rules (I didn't answer the question, I've asked for clarifications) because I don't have 50 in reputation so I cannot comment on the question asked.

Comment: I think I have to keep the places rather than translate - you can think of, say, cell[3,2] as indicating a proportion of a population choosing "3" over "2" which means these people can never choose "2" over "3" and so I need to keep track of them in the correct position.

Comment: Does the center of the matrix is always 0? 
Does the diagonal can take non-0 values?